# paperclip upload yml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, yaml

I have a problem with uploading yml file via paperclip. This is my how I try to do it:

In my model I have:

```
has_attached_file :search_config
validates_attachment_content_type :search_config, content_type: ['text/yaml', 'application/x-yaml', 'text/x-yaml', 'application/yaml', 'text/plain']
```

In my view:

```
<%= form_for @search, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %> 

<fieldset>
    <legend>Skills</legend>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :type, 'recommendation' %>
    <%= f.file_field :search_config %>
    <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
</fieldset>
```

In my controller:

```
def create
    @search = MailingSearch.new(params[:mailing_search])    
    if @search.save
        redirect_to action: :index, notice: 'Your search was successfully created. Search results will be send via email soon.'     
    else
        render action: :new
    end
end
```

I got an error, that

```
search_config_content_type=>["is invalid"]
```

When I try to create a file from console (I'm using the same file):

```
ms = MailingSearch.new
ms.search_config = File.open('tmp/test.yml')
ms.save
```

it works. What can be a problem here?

Comment: Given that parsing of YML-files lead to a bunch of security problems with remote code execution last year (basically YML allows embedded XML which allows embedded ruby) I would make extra sure that this is really what you have to do. Could you revert to a less dangerous format like JSON?

Comment: Yes, but this is temporary feature and it will be only used internally  by the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the debugger to check `params[:mailing_search]` in your controller.

I suspect `params[:mailing_search][:search_config].content_type` will be `application/octet-stream` since a .yml file is treated as binary.

Since you don't allow `application/octet-stream` as a valid content type, that's why you get the error.

When you try through the console the content type is not being overridden by the browser, hence why it works.

In your controller, before building `@search`, you can reset the content type in the params to the file's MIME type using:

```
params[:mailing_search][:search_config].content_type = MIME::Types.type_for(params[:mailing_search][:search_config].original_filename).first.content_type
```

This should preserve `text/x-yaml` as the content type for the file which you allow as valid.

Answer (score 1):

You do construct your MailingSearch in completely different ways in your example.

In your controller you constantize something that is probably `RecommendationMailingSearch` and create an object of this class by passing it `params[:mailing_search]` which does *not* seem to be part of your form.

In your manual example you instantiate an object of type `MailingSearch` and set a `File` object as the `search_config`.

It is obvious that you are doing completely different things, how do you expect them to behave in the same way?

Maybe by improving your question such that the object classes match each other and the method calls are more similar you will find the answer on your own.

Comment: You're right, it can be confusing. RecommendationMailingSearch is a subclass of MailingSearch (STI). I've edited my question to make it clear. I tried both with base class and sub class.